# SQL Server table data retrieval

Tags: sql

I have attended an interview recently, and the interviewer asked me this question:

```
UserId  UserName
1          Name1
1          Name2
2          Name3
```

Here he wants me to retrieve either Name1 or Name2 using where condition?

How can I get the result?

I wrote like

```
select Username 
from Users 
where Username = 'Name1' or Username = 'Name2'
```

but here both the conditions are satisfied so two records are returned... What will be the query to retrieve the data?

Comment: Retrieve Name1 or Name2 based on what condition?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "retrieve either Name1 or Name2" - if you want to get back a single row, you will have to have some unique value to look up. Is the expectation that given "Name1" or "Name2", you can get back the `UserId`? From the data you've given, the only way to get a single row would be to query on the `UserName` field.

Comment: Even i don't no what the reason behind this question In table he given the data same which added later he asked me to retrieve in using where condition how do u retrieve Name1 or Name3 using UserName column..i don't no weather the question is answerable or it's a false question

Comment: You wrote `Username` instead of `UserName`

Comment: please edit your questions. It's confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean something like this:

```
SELECT UserName FROM Users
WHERE UserName IN(NAME1, NAME2)
LIMIT 1
```

That would sort of randomly select the first one you come across (out of NAME1 and NAME2). I'm assuming that you don't have to select a specific one, and that there aren't more instances of the names that also need to get selected, all as per your example.

Comment: This is my first question in stackoverflow i asked many persons but i didn't get the answers so i posted here....Thanks for the reply's so is LIMIT will work in Sql Server

Comment: here the logic is he want where condition to be applied onName1 and Name3 but the result should come single name that is either Name1 or Name3

Comment: @hareeshbabu So wouldn't it be enough to substitute Name3 for Name 2 in the code above?